# How to check system tray availability programmatically?

Tags: perl, sh, raku, system-tray, notification-area

Upon launching [`QSyncthingTray`](https://github.com/sieren/QSyncthingTray) without any panel/trayer running, it displays an error dialog:

```
I couldn't detect any system tray on this system.
                                         [ OK ]
```

and exits upon pressing `[ OK ]`.

*Curiously though, if I have `QSyncthingTray` already running as a tray icon and kill my panel, `QSyncthingTray` doesn't quit, and upon restarting the panel `QSyncthingTray` is still there...*

For my `~/.xsession` & `~/.xinitrc` startup, I'd like to add a looped check whether a tray is present, pseudocode:

```
loop:
  if system-tray.is-available:
    run QSyncthingTray
    done
  else sleep 1
```

How do I do the `if system-tray.is-available`?
The preferable language is [`Perl`](https://www.perl.org/), also interested in [`Raku`](https://raku.org/) and POSIX `sh`.
Other languages are welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QSyncthingTray` uses [isSystemTrayAvailable()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsystemtrayicon.html#isSystemTrayAvailable) from Qt c++ lib.

You can do the same.

`is_tray_available.cpp:`

```
// program that exits with zero code when tray is available
// when not available (or program crashes) it should return non-zero

#include <QApplication>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  if(QSystemTrayIcon::isSystemTrayAvailable()) return 0;
  else return 1;
}
```

QT is unique in that you need to use a full-blown build system to build programs using it:

`is_tray_available.pro`:

```
QT += widgets
TARGET = is_tray_available
SOURCES += is_tray_available.cpp
```

Save both files in the same dir, execute `qmake`, `make` and voilà, you have an executable that you can use in a shell script.